# Toggle script inside a loop only works for first iteration

Tags: javascript, php, loops

Here is my php/javascript code. I have tried to write the script inside the loop but it doesn't work. This generates two buttons, one for local team, while processing local team, and the second for road team, while processing road team. These buttons show information contained in a div of a different class. For some reason, it works only for the local team, which its the first iteration of the loop.

I have read a lot about people using id's instead of classes, but this is not my case. I am quite lost.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
<script>
    $(".showavgloc").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".averageloc").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $(".showavgvis").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".averagevis").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
<?php
foreach ($teams as $team) { 
    if ($page=="game") { 
        if ($team==$locteam) { 
            echo "<button class='showavgloc'>Show average player</button>";
        }
        if ($team==$visteam) {
            echo "<button class='showavgvis'>Show average player</button>";
        } 
    }   
    if ($team==$locteam) {
        echo "<div class='averageloc' style='display:none'>This div has to be shown/hidden for local team</div>";
    }   
    if ($team==$visteam) {
        echo "<div class='averagevis' style='display:none'>This div has to be shown/hidden for road team</div>";
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us content example of `$teams`.

Comment: $teams is an array that contains two string variables: $teams=($locteam, $visteam)

Comment: Where are `$locteam` and `$visteam` defined?

Comment: Before the <script> tag $locteam="Example Local Team"; $visteam="Example Road Team";

Comment: You should probably focus on the generated HTML page and seeing it here may help getting a better answer.

Comment: Which part of the html code would you like to see? The button part is apparently correct: <button class='showavgvis'>Show average player</button>

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qfeo8j0x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

after that php code, and before close it ( before this "?>"), do an "echo" that contains:

```
<script>
    $(".showavgloc").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".averageloc").slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $(".showavgvis").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".averagevis").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

and try to use it as you want. This might help in some cases, because when you use the jQuery library and then you generate html throw code, the DOM keeps with the "initial" version an jQuery can't work properly because never find the controls. The right order is : Print controls and then bind jQuery events.

Good luck

Comment: I'm afraid it is still not working. The second button does nothing... Thank you in any case!

Comment: ok, it's 'kind of working'!! Now the second button works perfectly, while the first button do three things when clicking: show/hide/show. Or hide/show/hide. Amazing!

Comment: Can you use the browser console to inspect the document and tell me what do you see? the parts generated with php are there?

Comment: that it's strange... try to add   " event.stopPropagation(); " right before  " event.preventDefault(); " I think that can solve that little bug

Comment: Yes, the parts are there. Apparently everything is correct, except that the first button works three times...

Comment: This can smell...but, what about try to use a "Global var" that saves if the event can continue? For example

"var youCanGo=true;"

Then, use an "if(youCanGo){  youCanGo=false; /*  All the code of the event here  */ } 

And then check where you has to change to true for being ready for another click. It's a terrible solution but it can work until you/we get a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine when everything is included:

```js
$(".showavgloc").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".averageloc").slideToggle("slow");
});
$(".showavgvis").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".averagevis").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='showavgloc'>Show average player</button>
<button class='showavgvis'>Show average player</button>
<div class='averageloc' style='display:none'>This div has to be shown/hidden for local team</div>
<div class='averagevis' style='display:none'>This div has to be shown/hidden for road team</div>
```

My guess is that something else is amiss. Inspect your page to ensure all elements are printed properly by your PHP. If everything seems fine, you could try using the jQuery "on" function, which should watch for new elements that match the selector. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you. Apparently it works perfectly when used out of a loop. The problem is that both buttons are generated through a loop.

Comment: If the raw buttons and divs work as expected, then the only explanation is that the loop is not generating them correctly. Perhaps it is not generating the div when it should be. Can you post the rest of your PHP code that contains the portion where the rest of your variables are set? Have you inspected the page using Chrome's inspect tool to see if the correct divs are actually there?

Comment: It finally works! It was about the placing of the <script></script> part. I have tried to put it by the end of the code (well below the relevant loop) and it worked... Thanks to everybody.